# Is it possible to post video on Facebook user timeline using Facebook Autopost module?

Tags: 7, social-network

I need to upload videos to Facebook and I'm using [Facebook Autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost) and **Rules** module.

I've followed the video tutorials from:

- [Facebook Autopost](https://vimeo.com/56026903)
- [Drupal & Facebook : How to Post Drupal content on Facebook P 2/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zk9W0Lpkdb8)
- [Drupal & Facebook : How to Post Drupal content on Facebook - Drupal 7, Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgfcaU_SUL4).

They teach how to post images and text but none mention videos. How can I upload videos with this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not without building upon it. While the version of the [FB PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk) (3.2.3) that the module relies on supports [uploading video](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4806/how-to-upload-a-video-to-facebook-using-php-sdk-3-2), there is no support for it in the module.

Looking at the current module, it looks possible to build in support. For example, take the scenario where the module supports uploading an image to the user timeline:

- The rule action triggers [`rules_action_publish_to_facebook_timeline()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/fb_autopost_entity/fb_autopost_entity.rules.inc?h=7.x-1.4#n186) which retrieves (in [`facebook_autopost_entity()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/fb_autopost_entity/fb_autopost_entity.module?h=7.x-1.4#n635)) a [`FBAutopostEntityPhoto`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/class/FBAutopostPhoto.php?h=7.x-1.4) object which is extended from the [`FBAutoPostEntity`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/class/FBAutopost.php?h=7.x-1.4) class.
- When [`FBAutoPostEntity::publishEntity()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/fb_autopost_entity/class/FBAutopostEntity.php?h=7.x-1.4#n30) is called to publish the entity, it calls a parent method [`FBAutopost::publish()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/class/FBAutopost.php?h=7.x-1.4#n157) which [checks](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/class/FBAutopost.php?h=7.x-1.4#n164) a list of types that does include a [`video` type](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fb_autopost/tree/class/FBAutopost.php?h=7.x-1.4#n84).

Presumably, one could extend another class (e.g. `FBAutopostEntityVideo`) from `FBAutoPostEntity` that would add the various details for base classes that would allow it to plug in to the underlying SDK.

To sum it up, the existing module doesn't support however there's some support at lower levels in the code. That comes with the caveat that there might be more overhead to add (e.g. is there more to defining a Video entity than just extending the `FBAutoPostEntity` class) than what I mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in `admin/structure/facebook-publications` there is the `Add facebook publication type`, Can I define new publication type that supports video? and if yes how can I connect its fields with Facebook?

Comment: It looks like the entity machine name does correspond with the `$type` var so that gets you halfway there. As mentioned, `facebook_autopost_entity()` will still return a `FBAutoPostEntity` object which won't define the extra parameters needed. You could follow the pattern set by `FBAutopostEntityPhoto` where its setting the `source` / `name` parameters  from the entities Source/Title fields in the `publishParameterPrepare()` method. It looks like in order to implement this you'll probably have to define your own custom action that builds off what the module has supplied you.